# Mnist dataset splitting

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, training-data, mnist

can anyone help me out in splitting mnist dataset into training , testing and validation as per our wish of ratios.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Use 70-20-10 split for training, validation and testing.

Comment: Hi @TaranjeetSinh! Please check out my answer and if it's what you were looking for, please, consider accepting it as the correct one

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you do not want to maintain the default split between train and test provided by `tf.keras.datasets.mnist` API you can add toghether train and test sets and then iteratively split them into train, val and test based on your ratios.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

DATASET_SIZE = 70000
TRAIN_RATIO = 0.7
VALIDATION_RATIO = 0.2
TEST_RATIO = 0.1

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

X = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
y = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
```

If you want the datasets to be **numpy arrays** you can use the `sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split()` function.
Here an example:

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=(1-TRAIN_RATIO))
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_val, y_val, test_size=((TEST_RATIO/(VALIDATION_RATIO+TEST_RATIO))))
```

If you prefer to use the tf **Dataset** API then you can use the `.take()` and `.skip()` methods as follows:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))

train_dataset = dataset.take(int(TRAIN_RATIO*DATASET_SIZE))
validation_dataset = dataset.skip(int(TRAIN_RATIO*DATASET_SIZE)).take(int(VALIDATION_RATIO*DATASET_SIZE))
test_dataset = dataset.skip(int(TRAIN_RATIO*DATASET_SIZE)).skip(int(VALIDATION_RATIO*DATASET_SIZE))
```

Furthermore, you could add the `.shuffle()` to your dataset before the split to generate shuffled partitions:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle()
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach should do it. It basically uses iteratively the `train_test_split` function from tensorflow to split dataset into validation-test-train:

```
train_ratio = 0.70
validation_ratio = 0.20
test_ratio = 0.10

# train is now 70% of the entire data set
# the _junk suffix means that we drop that variable completely
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataX, dataY, test_size=1 - train_ratio)

# test is now 10% of the initial data set
# validation is now 20% of the initial data set
x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=test_ratio/(test_ratio + validation_ratio))
```

Comment: could you add a call where and how you got `dataX` and `dataY` from?